# react-native-google-mobile-ads age limitation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob, ads, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I've built an app using react-native and i'm using: react-native-google-mobile-ads  and im trying to show ads that are only familey friendly.
how can i do this in react native?

```js
import { View } from "react-native";
import {
  BannerAd,
  BannerAdSize,
  TestIds,
} from "react-native-google-mobile-ads";

const adUnitId = __DEV__
  ? TestIds.BANNER
  : "ca-app-pub-8453281779869033/5007999033";

export default function BottomBanner() {
  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <BannerAd
        style={{ width: "100%", height: 100 }}
        unitId={adUnitId}
        size={BannerAdSize.FULL_BANNER}
        requestOptions={{
          requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

tried searching the docs

Comment: I am using the same code my app is in production and the ads working fine till last week but now all of a sudden it stopped working I did not change anything there is no error when I run the app in development and also ad console is working fine. can you help me what can be the reason

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   import {MaxAdContentRating,} from "react-native-google-mobile-ads";
   ```
2. Add this to your `requestOptions`:

   ```
   maxAdContentRating: MaxAdContentRating.PG,
   tagForChildDirectedTreatment: true,
   tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true
   ```

Comment: I am using the same code my app is in production and the ads working fine till last week but now all of a sudden it stopped working I did not change anything there is no error when I run the app in development and also ad console is working fine. can you help me what can be the reason

Comment: Where did you find this information? I struggled a lot searching for it